# nested try and catch....before i tried else if statement....but session wasn't recognizing it

Tags: try-catch

Help me how to get this right ?? I have written this code in if....else if statement as under:

but now i have tried try and catch but its errorfull...

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
        try
        {
            Label1.Text = Session["FacultyFirstName"].ToString();
            try
            {
                Label1.Text = Session["AccEmployeeName"].ToString();
                try
                {
                    Label1.Text = Session["AccEmployeeName"].ToString();
                }
            } 
        }

        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** thing you have no `catch` or `finally` for many of your `try` blocks. You need to have a `catch` or `finally` for each one of your `try` blocks.

**Second** you are assigning every one of the names to `Label1.text`,well that seems to be a logical error.

**Third** Just do it this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
        Label1.Text = Session["FacultyFirstName"].ToString();
        Label1.Text = Session["AccEmployeeName"].ToString();
        Label1.Text = Session["AccEmployeeName"].ToString();
    }
    catch (System.NullReferenceException)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Do note here that you are using exceptions to control program flow, which is not considered good practice. Also if i understand your code correctly, there are many ways to redirect the user to the login page when the session has expired. Do look at form authentication etc.

Some links:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988457/check-session-variable-and-redirect-to-login-page-before-page-load`

`http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/detecting-session-timeout-and-redirect.html`

Comment: i just wanted a user to see his/her name in "welcome username" on the masterpage when he/she logs in....if he or she is registered user...or else just redirect them back to login page....which i saw in a video...even i don't think its needed...caz login page already checks it...but anyways..if it makes any sense to u in removing it just let me know.. :)