# ASP.NET Session & Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created **MasterPage.aspx** and other **Pages**.I want if user Click on **MainPage** anywhere on any `link` or `button` without `Login` it must redirect to my **Login.aspx**.
How can i will create `session` for this ?.I need idea weather i will code in **MasterPage.cs** **Page_load** `Method` or elsewhere ?.
**MasterPage.aspx**
{
//code here 
}
**Login.aspx**
{
//code here 
}

Answer (score 0):

Use condition like this on master page:

```
if (Session["LoggedUserName"] == null && !Request.Path.EndsWith("login.aspx"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/your/path/login.aspx");
    }
```

You can also use: `MembershipProvider`

This can be see here:

[Check Session variable and Redirect to login page before page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988457/check-session-variable-and-redirect-to-login-page-before-page-load)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help .But here when i open my main page it automatic redirect to Loing.aspx.I need if i click on any `link` or `button` on page then it must ask for `login` and redirect to Login.aspx.

Comment: Try to first check your session value if its null then it will redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily put your code in Page_load event of MasterPage :

```
if(Session["Login"] == null)
{
   Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
}
```

Update :

If you use the MasterPage for all of pages , automatically clicking on all of anchors cause to checking the session, but if you didn't use MasterPage for all, i think you can do this solution :

First Of All, create a class like this :

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if(Session["User"] == null) 
                {
                      Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
                }
    }
}
```

After that, when creating pages, inheritance them from `MyPage` class, for example :

```
public class Default: MyPage
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply .kindly see my comment on @Systematix Infotech Answer

Answer (score 0):

In login page use this code

```
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (txtuser.Text == "User" && txtPassword.Text == "Password")
                {
                    Session["username"] = txtuser.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password";
                }
        }
```

In Master page use this code in load event

```
        if(Session["username"]==null)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try The following code in MasterPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you well. Let me Know if get Helped.